# Help with a definition: number theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, definition

I found on some papers in number theory the following: 'Let $K$ be a number field and let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $K$ with absolute degree $1$".

What does absolute degree mean? I have ever heard about it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Fields hasn’t non-trivial ideals

Comment: But we have https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033901/prime-ideals-of-the-ring-of-integers-of-an-algebraic-number-field

Comment: @janmarqz actually it is an abuse of notation that I find everywhere. Many people write prime ideal of $K$ to indicate a prime ideal of $\mathcal O_K$. This is not so confusing thanks to the fact that everybody knows that fields have only trivial ideals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a context where you're discussing something regarding on a *field extension* rather than merely a *field* (e.g. the norm operation), I've seen the adjective "absolute" used to mean that you're taking $\mathbb{Q}$ as the base field.

The *degree* of a prime ideal (of the ring of integers) is such a notion. I don't have a definition handy so I may have details wrong, but I think it goes like this.

> Let $L/K$ be an extension of number fields. Let $\mathfrak{q}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_L$ lying over the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$. The *degree* of $\mathfrak{q}$ (over $K$) is the degree of the field extension $[\mathcal{O}_L / \mathfrak{q} : \mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{p}]$.

So, the *absolute degree* would be where you plug in $K = \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Oh thanks, I knew of course the notion of relative degree, but I didn't think that absolute just means to take $\mathbb Q$ as the base field.

Answer (score 3):

A Google search found this in *Encyclopedic Dictionary of Mathematics, Volume 1* (page 219):

> a prime ideal of absolute degree $1$ is a prime ideal whose absolute norm is a prime number

The absolute norm is the norm $N_{K/\mathbb Q}$. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_norm#Absolute_norm).